# Java lists and the garbage collector

Tags: java, data-structures

I am doing a quick card game project in Java. I am storing the deck of cards as a node list. I think I am having trouble properly adding and removing from the list. Do you see anything that doesn't look right? I've been banging my head off the desk trying to figure this one out. **EDIT: Posted all the classes for you to see**

Card class

```
public class Card 
{
    private CardType theCard;
    private CardSuit theSuit; 
    private Card nextCard = null, previousCard = null;
    Card(Card card)
    {
        /*
         * Question - If I just set "this = c", would this 
         * object be pointing to the same object c? Or will 
         * a separate object be created from Card c
         */ 
        this.theCard = card.getTheCard();
        this.theSuit = card.getTheSuit(); 
        this.nextCard = card.getNext();
        this.previousCard = card.getPrevious(); 
    }
    Card(CardType theCard, CardSuit theSuit)
    {
        this.theCard = theCard;
        this.theSuit = theSuit;
    }
    Card(CardType theCard, CardSuit theSuit, Card nextCard, Card previousCard)
    {
        this.theCard = theCard;
        this.theSuit = theSuit;
        this.nextCard = nextCard;
        this.previousCard = previousCard;
    }
    //the suit order is spade, heart, diamond, and then club.
    public int getTotValue()
    {
        return theCard.getValue() + theCard.getFaceValue() + theSuit.getValue(); 
    }
    public int getFaceValue()
    {
        return theCard.getFaceValue();
    }
    public int getSuitValue()
    {
        return theSuit.getValue();
    }
    public String getFace() 
    {
        return theSuit.getFace();
    }

    public String getSuit() 
    {
        return theSuit.getFace();
    }
    public int getValue() 
    {
        return theCard.getValue();
    }
    public Card getNext() 
    {
        return nextCard;
    }
    public void setNext(Card nextCard) 
    {
        this.nextCard = nextCard;
    }
    public Card getPrevious() 
    {
        return previousCard;
    }
    public void setPrevious(Card previousCard) 
    {
        this.previousCard = previousCard;
    }
    /**
     * @return the theCard
     */
    public CardType getTheCard() {
        return theCard;
    }
    /**
     * @param theCard the theCard to set
     */
    public void setTheCard(CardType theCard) {
        this.theCard = theCard;
    }
    /**
     * @return the theSuit
     */
    public CardSuit getTheSuit() {
        return theSuit;
    }
    /**
     * @param theSuit the theSuit to set
     */
    public void setTheSuit(CardSuit theSuit) {
        this.theSuit = theSuit;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return (theCard.getFace() + " of " + theSuit.getFace());
    }
}
```

CardSuit

```
public enum CardSuit 
{
    SPADE("Spade", 4), 
    HEART("Heart", 3), 
    DIAMOND("Diamond", 2), 
    CLUB("Club", 1);
    private final String face;
    private final int value; 
    CardSuit(String face, int value)
    {
        this.face = face;
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getFace()
    {
        return face;
    }
    public int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

CardType

```
    public enum CardType 
    {
            ACE("Ace", 11),
            KING("King", 3, 10),
            QUEEN("Queen", 2, 10),
            JACK("Jack", 1, 10),
            TEN("Ten", 10),
            NINE("Nine", 9), 
            EIGHT("Eight", 8),
            SEVEN("Seven", 7),
            SIX("Six", 6),
            FIVE("Five", 5),
            FOUR("Four", 4),
            THREE("Three", 3),
            DEUCE("Deuce", 2);
            private final String face;
            private final int value; 
            private int faceValue = 0; 
            CardType(String f, int v)
            {
                this.face = f;
                this.value = v;
            }
            CardType(String f, int fv, int v)
            {
                this.face = f;
                this.faceValue = fv; 
                this.value = v;
            }
            public String getFace()
            {
                return face;
            }
            public int getValue()
            {
                return value;
            }
            public int getFaceValue()
            {
                return faceValue; 
            }

    }
```

Deck

```
/**
 * 
 */

/**
 * @author Andrew-Desktop
 *
 */
public class Deck extends Pile 
{
    /**
     * the suit order is spade, heart, diamond, and then club.
     */
    public Deck() 
    {
        for(CardType card: CardType.values())
        {
            for(CardSuit suit: CardSuit.values())
            {
                this.addLastCard(new Card(card, suit));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param topCard
     * @param bottomCard
     */
    public Deck(Card topCard, Card bottomCard) 
    {
        super(topCard, bottomCard);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @param topCard
     * @param bottomCard
     * @param nCard
     */
    public Deck(Card topCard, Card bottomCard, int nCard) 
    {
        super(topCard, bottomCard, nCard);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

Pile

```
import java.util.Random;



public class Pile 
{
    private static final int GREATER_THAN = 1;
    private static final int EQUAL_TO = 0;
    private static final int LESS_THAN = -1;
    Card topCard, bottomCard;
    int nCard;
    Random ran = new Random();
    int ranNum; 
    Pile()
    {
        topCard = null;
        bottomCard = null;
        nCard = 0; 
    }
    Pile(Card topCard, Card bottomCard)
    {
        this.topCard = topCard;
        this.bottomCard = bottomCard;
        this.nCard = 52;
    }
    Pile(Card topCard, Card bottomCard, int nCard)
    {
        this.topCard = topCard;
        this.bottomCard = bottomCard;
        this.nCard = nCard;
    }
    public void 
    shuffle() throws InterruptedException
    {
        for(int i = ran.nextInt(10000);0<i;i--)
        {
            Card tempCard = remove(1);
            this.insert(tempCard, (ran.nextInt(52)+1));
        }
    }
    public boolean 
    thereIsDuplicates()
    {
        Card travCard = topCard;
        for(int x = 1; x<=nCard && travCard != null; x++)
        {
            for(int y = x+1; y<=nCard; y++)
            {
                if(travCard == this.getCardAtIndex(y))
                {
//                  System.out.println(this.getIndexOfCard(travCard) + ": " + travCard);
                    System.out.println(travCard.toString());
                    return true; 
                }
            }
            travCard = travCard.getNext();
        }
        return false; 
    }
    public 
    Card remove(Card c)
    {
        assert !isEmpty();//Don't know if this even works
        if(c == topCard)// if topCard
        {
            topCard = topCard.getNext();
            topCard.setPrevious(null);
        }
        else if(c == bottomCard) // if bottom card
        {
            bottomCard = bottomCard.getPrevious();
            bottomCard.setNext(null);
        }
        else
        {
            Card tempCard = c.getPrevious();
            tempCard.setNext(c.getNext());
            tempCard.getNext().setPrevious(tempCard);
        }
        nCard--;
        return null; 
    }
//  public void 
//  remove(int i) 
//  {
//      assert (i>0 && i <= nCard && !isEmpty());
//      if(i == 1)// if topCard
//      {
//          topCard = topCard.getNext();
//          topCard.setPrevious(null);
//      }
//      else if(this.getCardAtIndex(i).getNext()==null) // if bottom card
//      {
//          bottomCard = bottomCard.getPrevious();
//          bottomCard.setNext(null);
//      }
//      else
//      {
//          Card cardBefore = this.getCardAtIndex(i-1);
//          cardBefore.setNext(cardBefore.getNext().getNext());
//          cardBefore.getNext().setPrevious(cardBefore);
//      }
//      nCard--;
//      
//  }
    public Card remove(int givenPosition) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        Card result = null; // return value

        if ((givenPosition >= 1) && (givenPosition <= nCard)) 
        {

            if (givenPosition == 1) // case 1: remove first entry
            {
                result = topCard; // save entry to be removed
                topCard = topCard.getNext();
                topCard.setPrevious(null); 
            } 
            else // case 2: givenPosition > 1
            {
                Card cardBefore = getCardAtIndex(givenPosition - 1);
                Card cardToRemove = cardBefore.getNext();
                Card cardAfter = cardToRemove.getNext();
                cardBefore.setNext(cardAfter); // disconnect the node to be removed
                cardAfter.setPrevious(cardBefore); 
                result = cardToRemove; // save entry to be removed
            } // end if

            nCard--;
        } // end if
        if(result == null)
        {
            this.printCards();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

        return result; 
    }

    /** 
     * <p>Precondition: index must be 0<i and i<53 or less than the number of cards
     * <p>Postcondition: 
     * @param i - The index of the card.
     * @return Card at that index. 
     * 
     */ 
    public Card getCardAtIndex(int i)
    {
        Card travCard = topCard; 
        assert (i>0 && i<=nCard && !isEmpty());
        for(int x = 1; x<=i && travCard != null; x++)
        {
            travCard = travCard.getNext();
        }       
        return travCard;
    }
    public int
    getIndexOfCard(Card c, int i)
    {
        Card travCard = topCard;
        for(int x = i; x<=nCard; x++)
        {
            if(travCard == c)
                return x;
            travCard = travCard.getNext();
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public Card 
    getCard(Card c)//don't think I'll need this method
    {
        Card travCard = topCard; 
        assert (!isEmpty());
        while(c!=travCard && null != travCard)
        {
            travCard = travCard.getNext();
        }       
        return travCard;
    }
    /**
     * Sorts from highest(Ace) to lowest 2
     * the suit order is spade, heart, diamond, and then club.
     */
    public void 
    addLastCard(Card c)
    {
        if(isEmpty())
        {
            topCard = c;
            bottomCard = c;
        }
        else
        {
            bottomCard.setNext(c);
            c.setPrevious(bottomCard);
            bottomCard = c;
        }
        nCard++; 
    }
    public void 
    sort()
    {
        quickSort(topCard, bottomCard);
    }
    private void 
    quickSort(Card start, Card end)
    {
            Card left = start;                         
            Card right = end;                           

            if (start != end)                   
            {
                    Card pivot = start;     
                    while (!(left.getNext()!=right))                   
                    {
                        while (compare(left, pivot) == LESS_THAN && left != end && left!=right) 
                        {
                                left = left.getNext();      
                        }
                        while (compare(right, pivot) == GREATER_THAN && right!=start && right!=left)
                        {
                            right = right.getPrevious();           
                        }
                        if (left!=right) 
                        {
                            swap(left, right);      
                        }
                    }
                    swap(start, right);          
                    quickSort(start, right.getPrevious()); 
                    quickSort(right.getNext(), end);   
            }
            else    // if there is only one element in the partition, do not do any sorting
            {
                   return;                     // the array is sorted, so exit
            }
    }
    public void 
    swap(Card one, Card two)
    {
        Card temp = new Card(one);
        one = two;
        two = temp; 
    }
    public void 
    insert(Card theCard, int givenPosition)
    {
        if(givenPosition>0 && givenPosition<=nCard)
        {
            if(isEmpty())// if an empty list
            {
                topCard = theCard;
                bottomCard = theCard;
                System.out.println("EmptyList");
            }
            else if(1==givenPosition)// if adding to the top of the pile
            {
                theCard.setNext(topCard);
                topCard.setPrevious(theCard);
                topCard = theCard;
            }
            else if(nCard == givenPosition) // if adding to the bottom of the pile
            {
                this.addLastCard(theCard);
                nCard--; 
            }
            else
            {
                Card tempCard = getCardAtIndex(givenPosition);
                theCard.setNext(tempCard.getNext());
                tempCard.setNext(theCard);
                theCard.setPrevious(tempCard);
            }
            nCard++; 
        }
    }
    //the suit order is spade, heart, diamond, and then club.
    public int 
    compare(Card one, Card two)
    {
        if(one.getValue()<two.getValue() || (one.getValue() == two.getValue() && one.getTotValue()<two.getTotValue()))
        {
            return LESS_THAN;
        }
        else if(one.getValue() == two.getValue() && one.getTotValue() == two.getTotValue())
        {
            return EQUAL_TO;
        }
        else if(one.getValue()>two.getValue() || (one.getValue() == two.getValue() && one.getTotValue()>two.getTotValue()))
        {
            return GREATER_THAN;
        }
        return -5;
    }
    public boolean 
    isEmpty()
    {
        if(0 == nCard && null == topCard)
            return true;
        else
            return false; 
    }
    public void 
    printCards()
    {
        Card travCard = topCard; 
        int i = 1;
        while(travCard!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(i + ": " + travCard.toString());
            travCard = travCard.getNext();
            i++;
        }
    }
    /**
     * @return the topCard
     */
    public Card 
    getTopCard() 
    {
        return topCard;
    }
    /**
     * @param topCard the topCard to set
     */
    public void 
    setTopCard(Card topCard) 
    {
        this.topCard = topCard;
    }
    /**
     * @return the bottomCard
     */
    public Card 
    getBottomCard() 
    {
        return bottomCard;
    }
    /**
     * @param bottomCard the bottomCard to set
     */
    public void 
    setBottomCard(Card bottomCard) 
    {
        this.bottomCard = bottomCard;
    }
    /**
     * @return the nCard
     */
    public int 
    getnCard() 
    {
        return nCard;
    }
    /**
     * @param nCard the nCard to set
     */
    public void 
    setnCard(int nCard) 
    {
        this.nCard = nCard;
    }
}
```

TwentyOne

```
public class TwentyOne 
{

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        Deck theDeck = new Deck(); 
        theDeck.printCards();
        theDeck.shuffle();
        theDeck.printCards(); 
    }

}
```

The output looks something like this:

```
577625: Ace of Spade
577626: Nine of Spade
577627: Five of Diamond
577628: Ten of Heart
577629: Eight of Heart
577630: Nine of Club
577631: Jack of Heart
577632: Eight of Spade
577633: Queen of Heart
577634: Seven of Heart
577635: Deuce of Club
577636: Jack of Diamond
577637: Four of Club
577638: Five of Club
577639: Ace of Spade
577640: Nine of Spade
577641: Five of Diamond
577642: Ten of Heart
577643: Eight of Heart
577644: Nine of Club
577645: Jack of Heart
577646: Eight of Spade
577647: Queen of Heart
577648: Seven of Heart
577649: Deuce of Club
577650: Jack of Diamond
577651: Four of Club
577652: Five of Club
577653: Ace of Spade
577654: Nine of Spade
577655: Five of Diamond
577656: Ten of Heart
577657: Eight of Heart
577658: Nine of Club
577659: Jack of Heart
577660: Eight of Spade
577661: Queen of Heart
577662: Seven of Heart
577663: Deuce of Club
577664: Jack of Diamond
577665: Four of Club
577666: Five of Club
577667: Ace of Spade
577668: Nine of Spade
577669: Five of Diamond
577670: Ten of Heart
577671: Eight of Heart
577672: Nine of Club
577673: Jack of Heart
577674: Eight of Spade
577675: Queen of Heart
577676: Seven of Heart
577677: Deuce of Club
577678: Jack of Diamond
577679: Four of Club
577680: Five of Club
577681: Ace of Spade
577682: Nine of Spade
577683: Five of Diamond
577684: Ten of Heart
577685: Eight of Heart
577686: Nine of Club
577687: Jack of Heart
577688: Eight of Spade
577689: Queen of Heart
577690: Seven of Heart
577691: Deuce of Club
577692: Jack of Diamond
577693: Four of Club
577694: Five of Club
577695: Ace of Spade
577696: Nine of Spade
577697: Five of Diamond
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a standard java.util.List, and the standard java.util.Collections.shuffle()? You're reinventing the wheel.

Comment: What exactly does this question have to do with GC? And that's a rather complicated code for a linked list.

Comment: It would help if we didn't have to guess about your implementations of the various classes and methods.

Comment: I'll copy and paste all my classes to op

Comment: What's the question? You need to ask something more specific than "do you see anything wrong".

Comment: The nod remove doesn't seem to work or something else. When I call the shuffle method from TwentyOne it seems to get stuck in an infinite loop where it keeps adding cards to the deck(I posted the output above). I believe this happens when I add to the end of the list(or the beginning). Is my nod remove correct? Why is adding a large number of cards to the deck without removing them.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the java.util.List subclasses.  Either ArrayList (probably what you should pick) or LinkedList (in case your feeling froggy like you need something that implements Queue).  Then look at using Collections.shuffle() method to shuffle the cards.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)

LinkedList won't perform as well as ArrayList when it comes to random access.

Comment: I have to implement the the list class myself as this is an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the output like this makes it hard to figure out what is going on. Something is wrong as the Queen of Hearts appears multiple times. Try testing your insert method without calling shuffle and remove. Testing one method at a time helps isolate the problem.

When you can see that you are able to insert all of your cards in order, see what happens when you remove a single card.